# Is there any difference between casting pointer to int and to character? in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocation, reinterpret-cast

```
#include <iostream>

char** make2D(const int dim1, const int dim2)
{
    char* toAlloc;
    const int size = (dim1 * dim2) + dim2;
    toAlloc = new char[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < dim2; i++)
    {
        toAlloc[i] = reinterpret_cast<char>(&toAlloc[(dim2 + (dim1 * i))]);
    }

    return reinterpret_cast<char**>(toAlloc);
}

int main(void)
{
    int dim1 = 8;
    int dim2 = 10;
    char** array2D = make2D(dim1, dim2);

    for (int i = 0; i < dim2; ++i)
    {
        array2D[i][i % dim1] = i + 100; // << Crash
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to allocate two dimensional array by a single allocation.
So, my algorithm was, first 10(which is `dim2` in this code) items has pointer to first item of each rows.

When I was try this by pointer to 'int',

```
int** make2D(const int dim1, const int dim2)
{
    int* toAlloc;
    const int size = (dim1 * dim2) + dim2;
    toAlloc = new int[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < dim2; i++)
    {
        toAlloc[i] = reinterpret_cast<int>(&toAlloc[(dim2 + (dim1 * i))]);
    }

    return reinterpret_cast<int**>(toAlloc);
}

int main(void)
{
    int dim1 = 8;
    int dim2 = 10;

    int** array2D = make2D(dim1, dim2);

    for (int i = 0; i < dim2; ++i)
    {
        array2D[i][i % dim1] = i + 100;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

it works fine but when I do this in char, it crashes in commented line in above code.

My thought of crashing was when I do `reinterpret_cast`, something happens because of memory size gap between pointer(8byte) and char(1byte).
So like, sounds like ridiculous... changing pointer(8byte) to int(4byte) was fine, but when I do cast more dramatically(8byte to 1byte), it causes some problems...

I have no idea why char doesn't work but int works.
Could you give some advice to make char case works?

Comment: That code is so wrong is so many ways. A `char` is usually 8 bits, a single byte. On a 32-bit platform a pointer is typically 32 bits. How would you be able to fit 32 bits of data in an 8 bit value? And on 64 bit systems pointers are usually *64* bits, eight times the size of `char`.

Comment: Not to mention that `toAlloc` isn't an array of pointers, and using it like that is just wrong (no matter if it happens to work or not).

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is a red flag. In 99% of the cases where you think you need a `reinterpret_cast` you are doing something wrong

Comment: use a `std::vector` or `std::array` for dynamic / fixed size arrays and wrap some index mapping around that for 2 or more dimensions. Anything else is unnecessarily complicated

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question yes there is a difference, a huge one, on many platforms a pointer might fit into an int, on very few platforms it will fit into a char. On modern PCs which are 64-bit none are safe ways to store a pointer.

Use containers such as [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if the size is static.
Try something like:

```
array<array<T, dim2>, dim1> variable{};
```

if you actually want a 2-dimensional array of type T; since you seem to need an array of pointers try something like:

```
array<array<T *, dim2>, dim1> variable{};
```

This will take care to make an array of the appropriate type to store pointers in for your platform, no matter how big pointers actually are, obviously you should replace T with the proper type of the data you want to point to, this will ensure pointer math is done properly for you.
Array types will have their size calculated at compile time, if you need dynamic sizes you should use vector, after allocation call [resize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) on the vector and all sub-vectors to make sure you allocate all the memory in as few passes as possible.

Please also don't use reinterpret_cast, or c-style casts, it's a recipe for disaster unless you know very well what you're doing.

Don't know what book you're reading or who is teaching you C++ but please change your knowledge source.

Using raw owning pointers is discouraged and the way you're using them is wrong in so many ways.
Never store a pointer in anything but a pointer type. Even in plain C you should cast to at least void * if you need to cast at all.

Please read about [unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) if you really want to store/pass pointers around directly.

If you insist on using raw pointers for containers please try building your code with sanitizers such as address sanitizer, memory sanitizer (these are supported at least by clang and gcc, possibly more compilers these days)

Comment: @user463035818 while I agree with your point of view I think people learning the language should not be encouraged to use them because they will fall into traps like casting them to ints

Comment: @xception `reinterpret_cast` is probably what should be withheld then, not pointers.

Comment: yes there is, a huge danger, most PCs nowadays are 64-bit and an int on them is 32-bit, also it's a huge pain if you care about portability to other platforms, not to mention it's a disaster if you want to do math on it as with math on pointers the compiler takes care for you of the size of the contained type, while with ints you have to take care of it yourself

Comment: added the warning about reinterpret_cast as suggested, you are right about those, also updated the text to read raw owning pointers, that's also correct

Answer (score 0):

Issue is "incompatibility" of size of objects:

- `sizeof(char)` is `1`
- `sizeof(int)` is generally `4` or `8` (but at least `2`).
- `sizeof(T*)` which is generally `4` or `8`, `std::uintp_t` can hold `void*` value, which is not necessary the case with `int` (and even less with `char`).

You cannot store safely `void*` into `char` or `int`. It happens it's working for you for `int`, but it is not portable.

`reinterpret_cast` is generally the wrong tool.

Simpler would be to create a `class Matrix`, with `std::vector<T>` and accessor to fix indexing. (You might even have proxy to allow `m[2][3]` syntax).

With owning raw pointer, you need need placements new, and provide correct deleter...